# cvs rtag: [07:34:59] waiting for cvsuser's lock in

Tags: cvs

When I do rtag the process is rather slow with the message cvs rtag: [07:34:59] waiting for cvsuser's lock in ...; what causes this and how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Searching via Google for "cvs waiting for lock" returns plenty of results. This is the first result I see and it covers everything you need:

- http://durak.org/sean/pubs/software/cvsbook/CVS-says-it-is-waiting-for-a-lock_003b-what-does-that-mean_003f.html

But in essence, someone else is in the middle of a CVS operation. Wait for it to complete.

If you know that this isn't the case (eg. you spoke to that user) then their cvs operation failed and left a lock file behind. Delete it. See the link for details.

Answer (score 1):

The information in the link given by Burhan Ali is out of date. The latest incarnation of cvs seems to store locks in $CVSROOT/locks/project/directory... so if the message is "Waiting for foo's lock in /home/cvs/myproject/html" the lock file is in /home/cvs/locks/myproject/html with an owner of foo. The name of the lock file starts with #cvs but there only seem to be lock files there.