# os161 commiting changes via cvs

Tags: repository, cvs, os161

While I was committing to cvs my connection to the server got reset and I had to close my window now after getting back the connection, I am again trying to commit my changes to cvs and  it keeps on saying
`cvs commit: [14:18:31] waiting for MYUSERNAME lock in /home/USER..my folder path`

I also searched for cvs abort or similar command but there is not any.

what should I do now?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204963/cvs-rtag-073459-waiting-for-cvsusers-lock-in